# Mobilefirst issues with oauth login security flow and tokens

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst

We have an issue in a distributed environment where when we login, with our authentication adapter.  After a while, users session is redirected to login.

Where are tokens stored on the mobilefirst server?  Is that configurable?

Comment: In the mobile first console you can specify the token expiration time.

Comment: I was more looking for the architecture and how are tokens stored within mobilefirst and are there any configurations around that.